# Check same long condition on two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two columns `X` and `Y` and a where statement as following:

```
WHERE (x=0 or x=1 or x=4 or x=6 or x=7 or x=12 or x=75) and 
      (y=0 or y=1 or y=4 or y=6 or y=7 or y=12 or y=75)
```

since it's the same condition on both columns of the same table is there a way to short it?

Something like `x and y are (0 or 1 or 4....)` - it's not PostgreSQL syntax but its clarify the question.

Note: the numbers represent statuses, there is no mathematical logic behind this condition.

Comment: @SQLPolice I agree, i have reverted tags, we should delete comments now to avoid confusion to future readers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Provided that you don't need it to use an index on `x` or `y`, the simplest way is probably:

```
...WHERE ARRAY[x,y] <@ ARRAY[0,1,4,6,7]
```

Comment: Best and cleanest answer

Answer (score 6):

You may put the values into an array and the array into a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).

Assuming the existence of `tablename(x int, y int)`:

```
with list(arr) as (select array[0,1,4,6,7])
select x,y from list,tablename where x=any(arr) and y=any(arr);
```

Comment: it gives  `ERROR: column "arr" does not exist`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE x IN (0, 1, 4, 6, 7, 12, 75)
AND y IN (0, 1, 4, 6, 7, 12, 75)
```

Data:

```
x  y
0  0
1  1
4  4
6  6
7  7
12 12
75 75
```

Output:

```
x  y
0  0
1  1
4  4
6  6
7  7
12 12
75 75
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5f0f5/1/0

With Nulls in data:

```
x     y
0     0
1     1
4     null
6     6
null  7
12    12
75    75
```

Adapted code as they are no longer integers:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE x IN ('0', '1', '4', '6', '7', '12', '75')
AND y IN ('0', '1', '4', '6', '7', '12', '75')
```

Output:

```
x   y
0   0
1   1
6   6
12  12
75  75
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b57f7/2/0

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Does the second one only work when its a single value.`WHERE 1 IN (x, y)`?

Comment: Yes. Or if you compare tuples: `(x, y) IN  ( (0,0), (1,1), (4,4), ...) ` would work

Comment: From what I know IN is a problem if x or y has empty fields (null values). I might have null values in the columns

Comment: @John in your original version the NULL values would be suppressed also.

Comment: this is from the postgreSQL manual : "if there are no equal right-hand values and at least one right-hand row yields null, the result of the IN construct will be null, not false."   this might cause a problem with the WHERE statement. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-subquery.html#AEN16778   In my original condition if it's no match it will return false so WHERE knows how to handle it, but with IN, the result of IN itself might be null NOT false... so WHERE will fail.

Comment: This is great because it is a portable query, that can be used in MySQL without any change.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
WITH vals AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (0),(1), (4),(6),(7),(12),(75)) AS vi(v)
)
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM vals v1 CROSS JOIN vals v2 WHERE v1.v = x AND v2.v = y)
```